# Angular : Print the message I get from the Response in DevTools

Tags: angular, response, devtools

I work with a WEB API server and I receive a Bad Request and I want to display the message I receive:
[image]

I used this to get a different type of error:
But I can't get to this status 400 message in the same way

```
},(e:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
      console.log(e.error.errors.Name[0])
       this.validationService.categoryValidation(e);
      
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get that response using `error` property of `HttpErrorResponse`.

So in your code that I guess is part of observable subscription:

```
observable$.subscribe(
  res => {
    // Do something
  },
  (e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(e.error);
    // Should print 'The Category Name is taken'
})
```

Aditionally you could get other properties like `status` with `e.status`.
For more info check [this](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse) link.